# Coin Change Problem (but with minimum number of coins)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm new to coding and I got an assignment where I needed to make a program that would give change for amounts less than a dollar in quarters, dimes, nickels, and cents. However, the assignment wanted the program to print the minimum number of coins needed (for example, if I inputted 58 cents then the output should be "2 quarters, 1 nickel, and 3 pennies" instead of "2 quarters, 0 dimes, 1 nickel, and 3 pennies". Essentially, if there is none of a certain coin, then the program shouldn't print it). I've been stuck on figuring out how to make it so that the program doesn't print any coin that isn't necessary.

This is what I have as of now:

```
amount = int(input( "Enter amount (1-99): " ))
twentyfive = amount // 25
ten = amount % 25 // 10
five = amount % 25 % 10 // 5
one = amount % 25 % 10 % 5 //1

print(twentyfive, "quarters", ten, "dimes", five, "nickels", one, "pennies")
```

Comment: Build your output string dynamically.  If a particular coin count is zero, don't include it in the output.

Comment: Use an `if` statement to check if the number is greater than zero before deciding whether to print it. You can write one `if` statement for each number.

Comment: @kaya3 When you mean number you mean the user input or the coins?

Comment: The numbers you want to print. You want to print them `if` they are greater than zero.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah okay, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the message dynamically, including only coins with a nonzero count.

```
messages = []

if quarters:
    messages.append(f"{quarters} quarters")

if dimes:
    messages.append(f"{dimes} dimes")

if nickels:
    messages.append(f"{nickels} nickels")

if pennies:
    messages.append(f"{pennies} pennies")

# print out all message parts, joined together with commas
print(", ".join(messages))
```

You'll need a bit more logic if you want to display "and" before the last coin amount.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just out of curiosity, I searched up the f formatting and it says that it is much faster than str.format(). Will the program still work if a str.format() is in the place of the f format?

Comment: You can use whatever method of string formatting you like.  I used f-strings in my answer just because I think they're neat.

Answer (score 0):

Or use `re`:

```
import re
amount = int(input("Enter amount (1-99): "))
twentyfive = amount // 25
ten = amount % 25 // 10
five = amount % 25 % 10 // 5
one = amount % 25 % 10 % 5 //1
s = f"{twentyfive}, quarters, {ten}, dimes, {five}, nickels, {one}, pennies"
print(re.sub('0, \w+, ', '', s))
```

Output:

```
Enter amount (1-99): 58
2, quarters, 1, nickels, 3, pennies
```

Answer (score 0):

You're solving the problem of printing a list with these requirements:

- more than three items should be separated by `', '`
- the final item should be preceded by `and`, if there's more than 1 item

Examples:

- `['1 dime', '2 quarters']` : `'1 dime and 2 quarters'`
- `['3 nickels']` : `'3 nickels'`
- `['1 dime', '2 quarters', '3 nickels']` : `'1 dime, 2 quarters, and 3 nickels'`

```
def nice_list(items):
    return ', '.join(items[:-1] + [('and ' if len(items) > 1 else '') + items[-1]])
```

Another problem you're solving is that you want to print a number with a noun, with the noun followed by an `'s'` if the number is not `1`. But, annoyingly, if the noun ends in `'y'`, you want to replace it with `'ies'`

Examples:

- `'0 dimes'`
- `'1 nickel'`
- `'5 quarters'`
- `'3 pennies'`

```
def number_noun(number, noun):
    if number == 1 or not noun:
        result = noun
    else:
        result = noun + 's' if noun[-1] != 'y' else noun[:-1] + 'ies'
    return f'{number} {result}'
```

But you also want to avoid printing anything coin you need `0` of.

So:

```
amount = int(input( "Enter amount (1-99): " ))
coins = [
    (amount // 25, 'quarter'), 
    (amount % 25 // 10, 'dime'),
    (amount % 25 % 10 // 5, 'nickel'),
    (amount % 25 % 10 % 5 //1, 'penny')
]
print(nice_list([number_noun(c, name) for c, name in coins]))
```

If you, like myself, don't like that the numbers of coins are now in the same list as the names of the coins:

```
amount = int(input( "Enter amount (1-99): " ))
coins = [
    amount // 25,
    amount % 25 // 10,
    amount % 25 % 10 // 5,
    amount % 25 % 10 % 5 //1
]
name = ['quarter', 'dime', 'nickel', 'penny']
print(nice_list([number_noun(c, name) for c, name in zip(coins, names)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answerers have inferred stricter requirements than your assignment probably has. Your sample output has commas and the word "and", so they have written code to produce output in *exactly* that format. I think they have made this more complicated than it needs to be, using lists, loops, slicing, and regexes for what is meant to be a beginner-level problem.

Since you said *"I'm new to coding and I got an assignment"*, it seems unlikely that your task specifically requires that you have to produce output in such a strict format - and if it did, this should be mentioned in the question. Based on your description of the assignment, here is what I think a beginner would be expected to write:

```py
if twentyfive > 0:
    print(twentyfive, 'quarters')

if ten > 0:
    print(ten, 'dimes')

if five > 0:
    print(five, 'nickels')

if one > 0:
    print(one, 'pennies')
```